# Integral over $\mathbb{R}^n$ as integral of averages (Rewriting a Riesz potential operator)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-analysis

I'm looking for a simple proof of the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality from the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal operator properties.

I found an article here: http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/PolyMethod/lect30.pdf
which seems to have the proof. I'm confused at a step though -- Lemma 3.1 in the notes. It says that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x-y) |y|^{-\alpha} d y = \int_0^\infty r^{n-\alpha-1} \frac{1}{\operatorname{Vol}(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y) d y\;  d r. $$

I can see that the LHS can be written in polar as 
$$ \int_0^\infty r^{n-\alpha-1} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} f(x - rv)  dv \; d r. $$ 
I can't see how to go from this surface integral to an average over a ball though, without assuming more about $f$.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change variables with $y=x+z$ and then use spherical coordinates you get
$$\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)\,dy=\int_{B(0,r)}f(x+z)\,dz=\int_0^rs^{n-1}\int_{S^{n-1}}f(x+s\sigma)\,d\sigma\,ds.$$
Then $$\int_0^\infty r^{n-1-\alpha}\frac1{\text{Vol}\,B(x,r)}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)\,dy\,dr\\=\frac1{\text{Vol}\,B(0,1)}\int_0^\infty r^{-\alpha-1}\int_0^rs^{n-1}\int_{S^{n-1}}f(x+s\sigma)\,d\sigma\,dsdr.$$
Now use Fubini to write the right-hand side as
$$\frac1{\text{Vol}\,B(0,1)}\int_0^\infty s^{n-1} \int_s^\infty r^{-\alpha-1}dr\int_{S^{n-1}}f(x+s\sigma)\,d\sigma\,ds
\\=\frac1{\text{Vol}\,B(0,1)}\frac1{\alpha}\int_0^\infty s^{n-1-\alpha} \int_{S^{n-1}}f(x+s\sigma)\,d\sigma\,ds\\=\frac1{\text{Vol}\,B(0,1)}\frac1{\alpha}\int_{
\mathbb{R}^n}|z|^{-\alpha} f(x+z)\,dz$$
Then just take  $y=-z$.